# Spectrum of large Hilbert matrices

Tags: matrices, sp.spectral-theory, asymptotics

Let $x_k>0$ be a increasing sequence of real numbers, such that
$$\sum_0^\infty\frac1{x_k}<+\infty.$$
Let us form the (infinite) Hilbert matrix $A\in{\bf Sym}({\mathbb N};{\mathbb R})$ with
$$a_{ij}:=\frac1{x_i+x_j}\,.$$
Mind that $A$ is trace class, thus the eigenvalues $\lambda_0>\lambda_1\ge\cdots>0$ are summable.

> What is known about the asymptotics of the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$, in terms of that of $x_k$ ? For instance, what do we know about the spectrum of $A$ when $x_k=(k+1)^2$ ?

Another form of the question is the behaviour, as $N\to+\infty$, of the spectrum of the truncated matrix $A_N$ in which $0\le i,j,\le N$.

Comment: Are you willing to change $\frac{1}{k^2+n^2}$ to $\frac{1}{(k+n)^2}$? Because then such matrices are known as Hankel matrices, and I found in a paper by Pushnitski and Yafaev a reference to a paper by Widom, in which he apparantly proved asymptotics $\lambda_n = \exp(-2\pi \sqrt{n} + o(\sqrt{n}))$ and for general $\frac{1}{(k+n)^\gamma}$, $\gamma > 1$, $\lambda_n = \exp(-\pi \sqrt{2\gamma}\sqrt{n} + o(\sqrt{n}))$.

Comment: I do not see why $A$ is trace class in this generality. Is this always true and I am missing something?

Comment: You are right, it is.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov I'm a bit suspicious about your formula for general $\gamma$: when $\gamma\to 1$, it still provides some fast rate of decay, while the operator gets certainly worse and worse and in the limit there is no decay at all. Of course, it *may* happen that it isjust $o()$ that deteriorates, but that would be a bit surprising.

Comment: @fedja yes, you're absolutely right. I copied the (incorrect) formula from Pushnitski and Yafaev, but in the Widom's paper he uses $\gamma-1$ instead of $\gamma$. So for $\frac{1}{(k+n)^2}$ it should be $\lambda_n = \exp(-\pi \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}+o(\sqrt{n}))$.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Based on a quick back of envelope computation, I would rather expect $(\gamma-1)/\gamma$ but Hankel may be a bit different from Hilbert, so I'll not insist here :-)